# Which React cycle method should I use to re-render component when redux state has changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The React doc are unfortunately unclear for me at my level of understanding.

What cycle method should I use here instead of componentDidMount()? I want this component to update Google Map every time it gets new state from `state.selectedShopInfo`.

In my app user is clicking some list and every time he clicks this component gets new data.

I'm checking it with `console.log(_.last(this.props.selectedShopInfo));` and it is working.

So what React cycle method should I use so **every time** `{ selectedShopInfo: state.selectedShopInfo }` will change `GoogleMap Component` will change as well?

```
    import _ from 'lodash';
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';

    class GoogleMap extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        const lastSelectedShopInfo = _.last(this.props.selectedShopInfo);
        if (lastSelectedShopInfo !== undefined) {
          new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
            zoom: 20,
            center: {
              lat: Number(lastSelectedShopInfo.latitude),
              lng: Number(lastSelectedShopInfo.longitude),
            },
          });
        }
      }

      render() {
        console.log(_.last(this.props.selectedShopInfo));
        return (
          <div>
            <hr />
            <div className="google-map" ref="map" />
            <hr />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      return { selectedShopInfo: state.selectedShopInfo };
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoogleMap);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your component will re-render anytime a `props` or `state` change. This is the default behavior for React components.

So your component will re-render, but the logic you have in `componentWillMount` will not be applied more than once.

To solve this, move that logic to a separate function and call that both in `componentDidMount()` and in `componentDidUpdate()`. Something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.mapsInit();
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(prevProps)) {
    this.mapsInit();
  }
}

mapsInit() {
  const lastSelectedShopInfo = _.last(this.props.selectedShopInfo);
    if (lastSelectedShopInfo !== undefined) {
      new google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
        zoom: 20,
        center: {
          lat: Number(lastSelectedShopInfo.latitude),
          lng: Number(lastSelectedShopInfo.longitude),
        },
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that completly solved my issue! Magic! Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course I will, but I must wait 2 minutes before I will be able to do that!

Answer (score 0):

You should render the map initially in `componentDidMount` and update the map in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Hmm, putting the logic inside `componentWillReceiveProps` would trigger the logic *before* `render()`, which may or may not "replace" the updated map with a "new" `div`. Not sure if this would work. But even if it does, it feels safer to do that logic once React has finished re-rendering - not right before.

Comment: @Chris Fair point, I just considered that the author wanted the lifecycle method when the props coming from the Redux store change. Also, as far as I understand it doesn't really matter, whether to do it before or after the render, as the div will be reused from the previous render.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right that nothing will happen, unless we re-order sibling components or something.